# Query is returning rows that do not exist

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have this query in my model in CodeIgniter:

```
function get_licenses_info($id)
    {
        $this->db->select('
            vendors.id as vendors_id,
            vendor_licenses.id as vendor_licenses_id,
            vendor_licenses.vendor_id,
            vendor_licenses.license_type,
            vendor_licenses.date_expires,
            vendor_licenses.license_num
            ');
        $this->db->from('vendors');
        $this->db->join('vendor_licenses', 'vendor_licenses.vendor_id = vendors.id', 'left');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

And this bit of code in my view:

```
foreach($licenses as $l)
{   
    echo $l['license_type'];
    if(strtotime($l['date_expires']) < time())
        {
            echo " expired on ".date("M, d, Y", strtotime($l['date_expires']))."<br>";  
        }
    else
    {
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
```

and this is what gets returned in the view:

```
Baldwin County
City of Pensacola expired on Jan, 04, 2017
expired on Dec, 31, 1969
```

I thought perhaps I had somehow gotten an extra row in my DB. But I checked, and there are only the two records that I put in there.  So I thought maybe the table was corrupt, deleted it and made a fresh copy with 2 new records...same issue.
Even weirder, when I deleted all the records, I got not one, but TWO 'blank' iterations.
I've googled this extensively and cannot find *anything* on this happening, not by searching for the problem with CodeIgniter or even for general mySQL work. Any advice would be appreciated.

Here is the vendor_licenses table:

```
╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════╦══╗
║                                                    ║  ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════════╬══╣
║ id vendor_id license_type date_expires license_num ║  ║
║ 1 2 Baldwin County 2017-02-03 NULL                 ║  ║
║ 2 2 City of Pensacola 2017-01-04 NULL              ║  ║
╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════╩══╝
```

and here is the vendors table:

```
+--------------+
| id is_active |
+--------------+
| 1 1          |
| 2 1          |
+--------------+
```

Comment: So the problem is that you aren't expecting anything to be returned?

Comment: I'm expecting the rows in the database that exist to be returned, which they are, but a row that doesn't exist is being returned at the end! I suspect it's something to do with my foreach loop....it's looping at least 1 too many times....

Comment: it looks like an issue with join. Would you mind including all the entries in `vendors` and `vendor_licenses`?

Comment: Have you checked what is in `licenses` before you loop through it? If it already has data you don't expect, the problem is in your query. If it is what you expect, the problem is in your loop.

Comment: Update:  Added the table to the OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reverse the JOIN.

You are doing:

```
SELECT fields FROM vendors 
LEFT JOIN vendor_licenses ON vendor_licenses.vendor_id = vendors.id
```

So you get a row for each record of vendors table. But I figure you are not interested in getting anything for vendor id=1, which has no information in vendor_licenses table (you get a not fully informed row).

Instead, try:

```
SELECT fields FROM vendor_licenses 
LEFT JOIN vendors ON vendor_licenses.vendor_id = vendors.id
```

..so that you get a row for each vendor_license record.

Or simply keep it as is, but not LEFT but RIGHT JOIN the tables:

```
$this->db->join('vendor_licenses', 'vendor_licenses.vendor_id = vendors.id', 'right');
```

Comment: Ok, that did work, but perhaps you can explain to me what a not fully informed row is? The query is specifically perfomed by vendor.id = 2 so I'm a little lost as to why reversing the join worked.

Comment: Oh, doing a 'right' join made it make sense for me.  THANK YOU!